# Laravel 6 Passport CSRF token mismatch

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I've just created a fresh Laravel 6 project, installed the Passport functionality ([Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#installation)) and wanted to try it out. Now, in Postman I try to access the default route **POST** */oauth/clients*, fill name and redirect arguments as expected.

At this point I'll get a **"CSRF token mismatch"** error, what could I be doing wrong here? I do know that this is pretty limited information to go on, ask away if more is needed.

Running the Laravel website with 'php artisan serve'.

Edit: Postman has Accept: Json/Application.

Comment: Remove `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,` from your middleware if you've added it and don't need it.

Comment: @DelenaMalan thank you, but I did not add it anywhere.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using this route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions for you:

1) Add `Content-Type: application/json` to your postman request.

---

2) Try to reinstall the client certificates by executing the command `php artisan passport:install`.

---

3) The CSRF check can be disabled for configured urls as stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf).

So try to add the following code to the `VerifyCsrfToken` class:

```
protected $except = [
    'oauth/clients',
];
```

I hope that some of those solutions will solve your problem.

Comment: I went for disabling to CSRF check for now, but I need to look in to how safe that would be.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `Conten-Type` header to your postman request? I use passport very often and never had such problems.

Comment: I mean `Content-Type` not `Conten-Type`.. Sorry.

Comment: what do you with the client secret and id displayed after installing passport

Comment: You need those to authenticate at the server. Or what do you mean exactly?